# Should Entry.author be a ForeignKey to User or UserProfile?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, I want to filter a `QuerySet` using a list of `User`s who the active user is `following`.

I've opted to extend the `User` class rather than replace it with a custom class, although I'm not sure that was the right choice.

Hence what I have is a `UserProfile` class, which has a `ManyToManyField` to other UserProfiles, and a `OneToOneField` with `User`.

My `QuerySet` looks like `Entry.objects.filter(author__in=request.user.userprofile.following.all())` but `author` is a `ForeignKeyField` to `User` rather than `UserProfile`, so I'm about to change `Entry.author` to point to `UserProfile`s instead.

So my questions are, in decreasing priority:

1. Is it right to have `author` be a `UserProfile` instead? Because then I have something like `entry.author.user.username` which is not intuitive.
2. Might it be better to just replace the builtin `User` class with a custom class which has the data I need?
3. Is it right for `UserProfile`'s `following` to be a `ManyToManyField` to other `UserProfile` rather than to `User`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't recommend this at all. As you said it's not intuitive, an
   author should be a user.
2. No, a one to one relationship to user is better than creating a custom user class.
3. I think it will look better if you connect followings to users. This way your original query will also work.

In UserProfile model:

```
following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followed_by")
```

In this scenario user.followed_by is a list of UserProfiles, but user.userprofile.following is a list of users.

Answer (score 0):

Since your users can follow each other and Entries are from those people, it makes totally sense to make the author UserProfile so that both models are logically in the same level